# Using A DropDown List Selection in an If Statement

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

OK, I've created a DropDownList associated with a search field.  What I want to do, is have the selection in the dropdown cause a method to trigger based on the selection, and to search on that. I thought I would do something like if List.contains, and base it on that, but it doesn't appear to be working.

I have an arraylist setup to populate the dropdown, and the beginnings of an if statement in my controller.

```
List<String []> propertyList = new ArrayList<String []>();

         propertyList .add(new String[]{"EmailAddress","Email"});

         propertyList .add(new String[]{"FirstName","First Name"});

         propertyList .add(new String[]{"LastName","Last Name"});

    mav.addObject("propertyList ", propertyList 

   if (propertyList .contains("LastName")) {

           \\Code that needs to fire

 }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **propertyList** is a list of **Objects** `(i.e Array of String)` ,
So

```
propertyList .contains("LastName")
```

will never satisfy the condition , You need to make `List<String>` Instead of `List<String []>`

or you can use `Map<String,String>` if you want a **Key value pair**

```
Map<String,String> propertyList = new HashMap<String,String>();

         propertyList.put("EmailAddress","Email");

         propertyList.put("FirstName","First Name");

         propertyList.put("LastName","Last Name");

   mav.addObject("propertyList ", propertyList);

   if (propertyList.containsKey("LastName")) { // Here you can check the key

           \\Code that needs to fire

 }
```

**Update**

**How to iterate Map in jsp**

---

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${propertyList}">
      <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
      <c:out value="${entry.value}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: If I make it List<String> then how do I set up with the 2 strings?

Comment: OK, so if I wanted to alter my jsp page to add the hashmap (and I did use a hashmap to start yesterday) for my drop down  Do I add the key where the options are and another value?
`code`
<c:forEach items="${propertyList}" var="property" begin="0">

              <option value="${property[0]}" label="${property[1]}"></option>

       </c:forEach>
`code`

Comment: I did thank you. I will try that, I just need to figure out how to update my jsp to accept that.

Comment: @JackParker Check out the updated information , about how to iterate map in jsp

Comment: thank you again. I just brought my code back to a state where it was yesterday, added everything mentioned, but now the dropdown is showing blank.  Yesterday, when that occurred it had to do with the placement of the return mav; statement in the controller this time. I don't know.

`code`
<label for="searchEntry">Search by </label>
 <select name="property">
  <c:forEach items="${propertyList}" var="property" begin="0">
<c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
 <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>
  </c:forEach>
 </select>    
 <input type="text" name="searcher" id="searcherEntry" /><br />

</form>

`code`

Comment: Does the hashmap randomize the placement of the values? I'm going through my debugger and instead of places 0, 1, 2 like they would normally appear they are like 9, 11, and 12.

Comment: Yes hashmap does not maintain the order if you need to maintain the order then you should use TreeMap

Comment: Is maintaining the order relevant to the issue I'm seeing? If the earlier spaces have null values, then it needs to iterate further back to get the information?

Comment: @JackParker , Firstly Replax don't get confused by attempting to solve multiple things at once , If you want to trigger an event on selection of a list you need to use Ajax so that the selected value from the dropdown can be sended to controller and you can solve the particular problem

Comment: I have rarely ever used Ajax, but I have noticed the problem once I got it set up.  It won't load, and gives me a nullpointer exception.